# What security software can I use alongside Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, antivirus, malware

What security software (preferably, free) can I use alongside Windows Defender to make my computer safer?

I have seen several posts on different forums about arguing whether or not Windows Defender (Windows 10 OS) provides enough protection for your computer, with some people arguing that it does (specially for Home users), and others pointing out that Windows Defender fails to block certain malware, that it is still not as good as other software and even suggesting you use a different antivirus entirely (such as McAfee or BitDefender).

So is there any security software that can run alongside Windows Defender and maybe make up for its possible flaws? I don't understand that much about security software and haven't seen many posts discussing this, so I'd really appreciate some recommendations. Thank you for your time!

Comment: As with every security question, the real question is, protection against what?

Comment: Like I said in the post, some people have pointed out that Windows Defender isn't great at stopping malware, but I'm no expert, which is why my question is more broad in that sense. For a home user, I don't know what kind of extra security would be necessary